# Java: Recursively list of FTP files and directories

Tags: java, ftp

I want to list of all files in all directories and subdirectories (Recursively) on FTP server and get full path to files ещ рфму something like this:

```
/www/www2/www3/1.mp4
/www/www2/2.mp4
/www/3.mp4
```

I have done this code but have problems: 1) For loop not stoppping, 2) Not showing full path:

```
package org.example;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        var ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        ftpClient.connect("xxx");
        ftpClient.login("xxx", "xxx");

        listFolder(ftpClient, "/");
    }

    private static void listFolder(FTPClient ftp, String remotePath) throws IOException
    {
        ftp.connect("xxx", 21);
        ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        System.out.println("successfull connected");
        ftp.login("xxx", "xxx");
        ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(remotePath);
        System.out.println("successfull logged in");

        FTPFile[] listFiles =null;
// listing files from the direcotry
        try {
            System.out.println("Fetching files from the directory");
            listFiles = ftp.listFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < listFiles.length; i++) {
                if (listFiles[i].isDirectory()) {

                    listFolder(ftp, String.valueOf(listFiles[i].isDirectory()));
                    System.out.println(listFiles[i].getName());
                } else {
                    System.out.println(listFiles[i].getName());
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception exception) {
            StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = exception.getStackTrace();
            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
            for(int i=0; i<=stackTrace.length-1; i++) {
                System.out.println(""+stackTrace[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not going to cut it as your recursion is including the connecting procedure and other unwanted stuff. You need to isolate just the listing in a separate method and recurse that

Answer (score 0):

Like many questions in SO, `System.out.println()` isn't printing values which identify the issue. Add this to inside `listFolder` will tell you one problem:

```
 System.out.println("listFolder remotePath="+remotePath);
```

You are passing in "remotePath=true". Fix by building the correct subPath of the sub-directory using `remotePath` as base:

```
  listFolder(ftp, remotePath+"/"+listFiles[i].getName());
```

Other problems are mentioned by @g00se - don't touch the ftp client inside `listFolder`, but move to the `main()`:

```
 ftp.connect("xxx", 21);
 ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
 System.out.println("successfull connected");
 ftp.login("xxx", "xxx");
```

Finally, print stack trace in one line - or better still don't catch it and make `listFiles throws WhateverException` it leave the method so caller can decide on sensible action.

```
 exception.printStackTrace();
```